# WSO2 EI encodes special symbols like "/", "&" and etc. when transforms from property to part of uri

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a sequence with string property that I added to end of uri string. If string has special symbols like '?','/' and etc, they encodes to uri encoded string and broke uri. For example:

```
api/res?param1=val1&param=val2
```

becomes

```
api/res?param1=val1%26param2%3Dval2
```

`api/res?param1=val1` - main part of uri

`&param=val2 = uri.var.param` part from Parameter Mediator that I had add to uri by template like: `uri-template="/api/res?param1=val1{uri.var.param}"`

Comment: You question is not very clear. If you could rephrase or clearly stat the problem and the intended result, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use legacy encoding for this purpose and it will just append without doing any change.

For example like follows

uri-template="/api/res?param1=val1{+uri.var.param}

Please note the + sign there.

Thanks